# What might be a secure way to transfer files outside LAN?

Tags: networking, network-programming, protocols

I am a complete novice developing an application which deals with securely transferring files from one peer to another without storing the said file anywhere. Any suggestions on how to do it?

I tried using SFTP but it requires username and password of the system which I feel are not secure to share. FTP also seems pretty unsecure.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.